# Issue with displaying image on React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, styling

I am having issue displaying some images from the same domain on React Native

```
<Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{uri: 'https://ubamarketplace.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/banner/hand.jpg'}}/>
```

but other images like the one below works perfectly.

```
<Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{uri: 'https://ng.jumia.is/unsafe/fit-in/500x500/filters:fill(white)/product/57/585671/1.jpg'}}/>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: no error per se, it is just showing an empty "space/view" with a  width and height of 100

Comment: I was able to replicate <Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{uri: 'https://ubamarketplace.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/banner/hand.jpg'}}/> in a react native app I am working on. The image loaded fine.